# When I try to pass large amounts of information using jquery $.ajax(post) method. it throws potential dangerous html error

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to create a preview window for my texteditor in my blog page. I need to send the content to the server to clean up the text entered  before I can preview it on the preview window. I was trying to use

```
$.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: url,
  data: values,
  success: LoadPageCallback(targetID),
  error: function(msg) {
    $('#' + targetID).attr('innerHTML', 'An error has occurred. Please try again.');
  }
});
```

Whenever I tried to click on the preview button it returns an `XMLHTTPRequest` error. The error description -

Description: Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted. This value may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. You can disable request validation by setting validateRequest=false in the Page directive or in the  configuration section. However, it is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all inputs in this case.

The `ValidateRequest` for the page is set to false.

Is there a way I can set validaterequest to false for the ajax call.Please advise

Thank you for reading my post.

**I am using ASP.net. How can i do htmlencode using JAVAscript/jquery?**

Comment: Can you post the content of `values`?

Comment: value could be normal text or html content copied from a webpage

Comment: Maybe you need to encode your HTML. Here's one approach to it: http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-submit-html-without-disabling/

Answer (score 1):

If `method` is `get`, it's possible that your request is too large for it, and your request is mis-identified as an attack.

Can you try using `post`?

Comment: I am using post. MY webserver is IIS 7.0.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm reasonably sure it's not a `get` vs `post` thing and more of a trying to submit unencoded html to an ASP.NET WebForm

Comment: @R0MAN yeah, the article you link to looks good. I'd post that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. ROMANARMY and Pekka's post nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

> The ValidateRequest for the page is set to false.

How are you setting that? Evidently it hasn't taken for some reason. You can also try in in the configuration:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

(inside `<system.web>`.)

Setting `validateRequest` to `false` *should* stop this error appearing, and is in general the right thing to do anyway. ASP.NET's “request validation” is 100% bogus. It does not and cannot protect you properly from XSS attacks, but it will happily screw up your apps like this.

Comment: I wouldn't say "100% bogus" but maybe "not efficient for many tasks". Obviously it can't stop a determined attacker. To tell people to just turn it off all the time sounds like bad advice.

Comment: It sounds like bad advice but it isn't. All Request Validation is doing is hiding bugs that are very likely still exploitable, and giving you a false sense of security. That's not worth the breakage it brings with it. An ineffective security measure is worse than no security measure.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to send the content to the server to clean up the text entered before I can preview it on the preview window.

If you're using ASP.NET WebForms, there's a good chance you're running into [this problem](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/).

> Request validation, a feature of ASP.NET since version 1.1, **prevents the server from accepting content containing un-encoded HTML**. This feature is designed to help prevent some script-injection attacks whereby client script code or HTML can be unknowingly submitted to a server, stored, and then presented to other users. We still strongly recommend that you validate all input data and HTML encode it when appropriate.